# Why Imputation converts float64 column to object and not converting again?

Tags: pandas, machine-learning, scikit-learn, statistics, data-science

I just did mean imputation on a pandas dataframe, but the column after imputation in converted to object type and is not converting back to float. I tried astype(float), which says need a string not a method, to_numeric() also donot work.

[this is it is converted to object](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jI1Iq.png)

[Applying astype() function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u8j0G.png)

[This is the error that comes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7OCTs.png)

```
# mean imputation
mean_age = df['Age'].mean
df['Mean_Age'] = df['Age'].fillna(mean_age)

# This makes the column to object and astype() and to_numeric() even donot work to convert it back to float
```

Comment: Take a look through [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and make sure all relevant information is included in the question. In general: [images of code are not useful](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors), and you are more likely to get help on this if it is written as a minimal reproducible example.

Comment: You need parentheses after `mean` in the first line; without them, `mean_age` is a function rather than the number you expect.